# Codeigniter Email attachment name not support Unicode?

Tags: php, codeigniter, unicode, phpmailer

I tried sending an attachment containing Unicode characters, and the attachment was  sent successfully. But the Unicode characters were removed from the file name. For example, if I send an attachment named `"你好.jpg"`, then the receiver will receive the file but it's named `".jpg"` (unicode characters are removed). I want to keep the original attachment name, is there any solution? Thank you very much!

`$this->email->attach("path/to/你好.jpg");` //attachment name contains Unicode characters

Comment: It's a bad idea to put exotic non-ascii characters in a file name.

Comment: Is your mailer set to use UTF-8?

Comment: @Synchro, yes, it's set to use UTF-8

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic It is very common for people to use their native language for the attachment name. It doesn't make sense if the file name cannot use Unicode characters.

Comment: @Tao Hu Just because it is common it does not mean it is good. That might also be the reason why non-ascii chars are being removed automatically. I would transliterate the file name instead.

Comment: To be fair, it should work. PHPMailer has no problem with Utf-8 in other headers (e.g. subject), so I don’t know why this is not happy.

Comment: @Synchro I also think it should work. there must be a bug in Codeigniter Email class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I finally solved the problem, just by adding the 3rd parameter to $this->email->attach(para1, para2, para3). Set the 3rd parameter to the Unicode name it will work. It is a workaround. I think it is a bug of codeigniter. It should work without the 3rd parameter.